# How many residue classes mod $p$ does the image of a polynomial with integer coefficients occupy? (Status of a question of Chowla)

Tags: co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, polynomials

In his 1952 AMS Bulletin article "[The Riemann zeta and allied functions](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1952-58-03/S0002-9904-1952-09583-5/)" Chowla asks the following:

> Given a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients, how many residue classes mod $p$ does its image occupy?

Chowla notes without references that Davenport has proven that for degree $4$ polynomials the number of residue classes is asymptotic to $5p/8$. My question is what is currently know about this problem?

Certainly this is reminiscent of Weil's theorem about the square root cancellation of polynomial exponential sums, but I don't see how to deduce a solution from Weil's estimate.

Comment: Have you seen https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7160.pdf, which has a discussion of such problems with references.

Comment: @Lucia: thanks! this lead me to the following note of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer on this exact question: https://eudml.org/doc/206420

Comment: The result you (or Chowla) attribute to Davenport is clearly false for the polynomial $x^4$.  Is there a hypothesis missing?

Comment: @Steven: This holds for a "generic" degree four polynomial. To understand what this means see the paper of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer.